# Searching for objects in array by name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, object

is there a possibility to check for an object in an array by name.
At some point in my app I need to access the plist and pull information stored under an object which I found by its name.
The reason I need to do this is because I don't have the integer number under which where the object is placed in my array.

I have started the usual procedure but i'm not getting anywhere. Maybe its just getting a little too late for me....

This is how my plist looks

```
Array
 Dictionary
      title ...
      text ...
      ect ...
 Dictionary
      title ...
      text ...
      ect ...
  Dictionary
      title ...
      text ...
      ect ...
```

My code so far isn't helping at all. I'm definitely doing something wrong.

```
-(NSString*)nameFromPlist:(NSString*)name {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Orte.plist"];
_regionArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:writableDBPath];

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in _regionArray) {
    string = [[dict objectForKey:name] valueForKey:@"title"];

}

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
```

}

My string is just returning null.

Any ideas anyone?
Thanks a lot!

ANSWER:

Here is the code for everyone:

-(NSString*)nameFromPlist:(NSString*)name {

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tmpFileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Orte.plist"];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFileName];

NSString *string;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *title;
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    title = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];

    if([title isEqualToString:name]) {
        string = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"Titel: %@", string);
    }        
}

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
```

}

Thank a lot everyone!

Comment: You should add a tag for the language of the code, then you have a better chance that your question gets answered.

Comment: There are several possibilities for unexpected results: Your `_regionArray` could be `nil`; also, in each iteration you discard the previous value of `string` and replace it with a new one, which could potentially be `nil`. Use the debugger to find out the actual values of the variables during execution.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to alloc the NSString, 'cause you'll get a different one from valueForKey.

Then if I understood right what you want to get a better code may be something that make use of `NSPredicate` or the block-based `indexOfObjectPassingTest`. Both iterate across the array and perform a test on the elements to get you the matching elements (or the index of them).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I finally figured it out. I put the code into the original question!

Comment: Great! Still I suggest you to have a look to the more efficient NSPredicates or block-based APIs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"<PlistFileName>" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableArray* titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary* d in array)
    [titles addObject:[d objectForKey:@"title"]];
NSLog(@"Object found at index %i", [a indexOfObject:@"<Your object name>"]);
```

Make sure you're testing against NSNotFound for failure to locate, and not (say) 0.